# gem command silently does nothing

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

I need to use Twitter's twurl command. In so doing I have installed Ruby and then Gem under Linux.

I've downloaded the latest version of twurl but when I attempt to use it to do an install it silently does nothing. I've also tried installing the oauth gem, but the same result. Gem must work because I can do a build using the gemspec file and it creates a gem file.

```
cam:~/twurl-master$ sudo gem build twurl.gemspec
sh: git: command not found
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55: command not found: git ls-files
sh: git: command not found
WARNING:  description and summary are identical
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: twurl
  Version: 0.9.2
  File: twurl-0.9.2.gem

cam:~/twurl-master$ ls
COPYING  Gemfile  INSTALL  README  Rakefile  bin  lib  test  twurl-0.9.2.gem  twurl.gemspec
cam:~/twurl-master$ sudo gem install twurl
cam:~/twurl-master$ sudo gem install twurl --remote
cam:~/twurl-master$ sudo gem list t

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


cam:~/twurl-master$ sudo gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/cam/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/cam/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/X11R6/bin
cam:~/twurl-master$
```

I am at a loss as to know what to do. I've searched on Google but nobody else seems to have this particular problem. No error message is highly unhelpful...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the issue and if that's related, but just in case, twurl gem also requires the gem oauth-0.4.7.